# What does t2-t1 represents in the expression t2-t1 = RC*ln|9|?

Tags: capacitor, oscilloscope, rise-time, time-constant

And how do I find t2-t1 with an oscilloscope?

I was given the following problem, I derived the expression in the title of the question and I need to use the oscilloscope to find t2-t1...

> Resistors can be readily measured with most any multimeter, but the
>   measurement of capacitors and inductors requires either more
>   specialized instruments or techniques. In this lab it is expected that
>   a 10% to 90% rise (90% to 10% fall) time for a RC circuit will be
>   used. Derive the required 10% to 90% rise time relationship for a
>   parallel combination of a square wave source and an RC pair. Note a
>   similar approach could be used to measure an inductor in a series RL
>   circuit, except here a sinusoidal source and voltage division is
>   utilized.

I have the following configuration (I meant to write 220uF but out 220mF) instead  [image]

I think t2-t1 is the rising time but is throwing me off that I have to measure them a whole period apart on the oscilloscope to get something close to my ideal values.

here is a screenshot of my oscilloscope
[image]

Comment: We might need more need more content as you could be referring to some sort of bandwidth. What are you measuring with the oscope? Also, a lot of oscopes have have axis markers that subtract the difference between the distance between each marker based on its placements. You can use those are just count the divisions yourself.

Comment: @KingDuken added context, hope it makes more sense

Comment: This is a duplicate question.

Comment: @Barry Would you be so kind to point me to the duplicated question?

Answer (score 1):

> I think t2-t1 is the rising time

Yes, t<sub>2</sub>-t<sub>1</sub> on your handwritten diagram (not on your scope trace) is the rise time of the signal (sometimes written as T<sub>r</sub>).

I have found some problems, which I've marked on a copy of your notes:

[image: annotated copy of original notes & schematic from the question]

Looking at the red numbers which I added to your photo:

1. The formula you are using is for a **series** RC network, but your schematic shows a **parallel** RC network. That's why you are not seeing the expected waveform shape.
2. In your rise time calculation, 0.00022 isn't 220**ms** as you wrote; it's 220**us**.

Also, the markings of t2 and t1 on your scope image are incorrect - you seem to be trying to find those points on your scope trace, but that trace isn't showing the expected waveform due to problem "1" which I explained above.

**Summary**: Change it to a series RC network, measure the voltage across the capacitor with your scope, and you should see approximately 220us rise time (T<sub>r</sub>), which matches your calculation.

Comment: Thank you for your input, yes I was aware that it was supposed to be 220uF, I guess I wrote it down by mistake. In terms of the formula and configuration, I'll work on it in series see what do I come up with but as of right now I believe the configuration should be in parallel since that formula I derived it using KCL analysis.
Iin=Ir+Ic   =>  Iin=Vin/r+C*dv/dt...

Answer (score 0):

t2-t1 is indeed the rise time (or fall time). You would need to zoom in with your scope to see the exponential rise/fall characteristic and to measure rise/fall time of this signal.

Comment: I tried, but if I do that and then I substitute the rise time (around 10us) into t2-t1=RC*ln|9| (using a 1kOhm resistor) and solve for C it would tell me that the Capacitance of C is 5pF when in reality I'm using a .1uF, so it has to be measured one period apart (and that is something that I was told as well from my TA) but haven't been able to understand why

Comment: First of all: Where does that ln(9) come from? I also think that your circuit setup is not OK. If the voltage source is a good (near ideal) source, then you can not measure the rise time with this circuit. Instead, you would need to form a serial R and C configuration and measure the voltage over the C.